# How to call any file (php) from a shortened url

Tags: php, url

I have made a url shortening service.
Let say long url is "www.bakjfbbcvns.com/vhsfbj/a/hgsvaksbdmfk/jajbk" (just random characters) and I have mapped it in my database to "wer34".
Hence I generate a short url mydomain.com/wer34.
Now I do not understand what to do when someone accesses this short url.
 I mean this, url will either look for a file named "wer34" or a folder named "wer34" in my home directory on the server,neither of which exists.

So please tell me how to make this url go to a file(php) with "wer34" stored in a string.

Comment: Then I guess you *haven't* made a URL shortening service .. which takes a *short* URL, looks up the *long* URL (or other interesting information), and then redirects-to or proxies the resource as appropriate. In any case, maybe you are simply looking for Apache's [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and request rewriting? (Request rewriting / mod_rewrite can change foo.com/s/fuuux to foo.com/myscript.php?k=fuuux or whatever else is appropriate to process the resource.)

Comment: I still cannot figure out , in which file(file is a php file on server) I have to put the code for request rewriting.  I mean when the url will load from where it will take the code to be rewritten.

Also , some code snippets to rewrite it as "www.mydomain.com/folder/file.php?var=wer34" wouls be very helpful

Comment: See http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/ , a basic example to "rewrite anything" is given on Page #2. Where the short URL's appear off of the "/s" resource, it would look something like `RewriteRule /s/([a-zA-Z0-9]+) /folder/file.php?var=$1` (It usually makes it easier if the rewrite URLs are mutually exclusive to target URLs, guaranteed with "/s" in the above examples.)

Comment: @user2864740 I went to the site you mentioned. I completely got a hold of how to use mod_rewrite. But, I still do not understand in which file I have to put the code for mod_rewrite.I have tried putting the code in .htaccess  and in index.html but none of them worked out

Comment: It belongs in `.htaccess` (it is instructions for Apache and is not html or PHP). There are a number of reasons why it may not be working, including wrong file location, mod_rewrite disabled (or disabled in .htaccess), or a rule that just isn't correct, etc.